# Efficient way to convert a String (representing HEX) to a byte array? Android

Tags: java, android, string, byte, arrays

I'm working on a project that involves receiving a byte array over wireless, the Android app reads this as a String over a TCP connection:

```
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
...
...
//Loop
String read = input.readLine();
//Do something meaningful with String read...
```

The String will always be of a fixed format i.e. the first 3 characters will be an ID and the next following 20 characters will be the message data. The amount of characters will not change (3+20 characters = 23, with a starting and ending character '[' and ']' so that's 25 characters in total.

An example of a String received by the application would be [01A01020304050A0B0C0D]

1. ID  - 0x01A
2. Byte0 0x01
3. Byte1 0x02
4. Byte2 0x03
5. Byte3 0x04
6. Byte4 0x05
7. Byte5 0x0A
8. Byte6 0x0B
9. Byte7 0x0C
10. Byte 8 0x0D

I would guess that I would have to use the substring operation, but I'm having trouble converting the substring to a byte value (note: the app is expecting byte[] and not Byte[]) and I feel I'm not doing it efficiently. I came across this piece of code that I've been using:

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
int len = s.length();
byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                         + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
}
return data;
```

This is returning a byte array of size 1 and will have to be run 9 times (9 bytes) per message. I'm a bit concerned that this may be a bit too strenuous on processing, especially when the application is receiving messages very frequently (roughly about 10-15 messages per second)

I appreciate any thoughts and many thanks in advance!

Comment: what's wrong with `String.getBytes`?

Comment: Use `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`

Comment: tell me why do you convert byte[] to String by using a BufferedReader and then you want to convert String to byte[]?

Comment: Strip of the brackets. Loop over the triples and parse the hex values. Not sure it would be more efficient but it would certainly be more readable...

Comment: IF I use the String.getBytes() method, it returns the ASCII representation and not the Byte representation for examples

String s = "BACB"
//byte0 = 0xBA (decimal 186)
//byte1 = 0xCB (decimal 203)
byte[] barray = s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
//barray[0] = 66
//barray[1] = 65
//barray[2] = 67
//barray[3] = 66

Comment: dont use **getBytes**, use clientSocket.getInputStream() and read the **bytes** from InputStream

Comment: @DavidEvans your title is misleading. Perhaps you want to clarify to "Converting Hex string to byte value".

Comment: I can see how it may be a little misleading however, it is certainly implied throughout the text that it's dealing with Bytes. I altered the title to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

just use this :

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(your_string, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best and simple way:

```
String myString = "This is my string";
byte[] myByteArray = myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Now, you able to access id, message whatever; easily from myByteArray.

Comment: IF I use the String.getBytes() method, it returns the ASCII representation and not the Byte representation for examples

    String s = "BACB"
    //byte0 = 0xBA (decimal 186)
    //byte1 = 0xCB (decimal 203)
    byte[] barray = s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    //barray[0] = 66
    //barray[1] = 65
    //barray[2] = 67
    //barray[3] = 66

Comment: rest logic something like this; separate id and message as you know first three are id. after that String id = new String(myIdByteArray); String message = new String(myMessageByteArray);

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] b = string.getBytes();
byte[] b = string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
byte[] b = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

There is no way to be more effecient than using this methods.

Comment: `There is no way to be more effecient than using this methods` a very mighty claim. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Anything wrong with `StandardCharsets.UTF-8`? I'm fairly sure this would be more efficient than parsing a `String` to a `Charset`.

Comment: I have tried it with a huge string and i took under 1ms. I also tried other conversions which took far longer.

Answer (score 0):

Just write your data like

```
  byte[] data = yourData.getBytes();
  os.write(data, 0, data.length) // data is of 23 bytes
  os.flush();
```

what about reading through InputStream, as you mentioned in your question that String is of 23 characters just do like

```
  public byte[] readData(InputStream is) {
         byte[] data = new byte[23];
         int read = is.read(data);
         System.out.println("Read: " + read);
         return data;
 }
```

When you have data then you can split data like this

```
  byte[] tempId = new byte[3];
  System.arrayCopy(data, 0, id, 0, id.length);
  byte[] tempMessage = new byte[20];
  System.arrayCopy(data, 3, message, 0, message.length);

  String id = new String(tempId);
  String message = new String(tempMessage);
```

Now you id and message separated and converted into String.

Answer (score -2):

```
byte[] array = String.getBytes("UTF-8");
```